# ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity

Tags: python

I am using some scripts from Github for a Telecine project, and am running into the following error (traceback included:)

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py:544: 
PiCameraResolutionRounded: frame size rounded up from 3280x2464 to 3296x2464
width, height, fwidth, fheight)))

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tc-setupjob.py", line 253, in mouse_handler
pf.findFirstFromCoords(img,(x,y),20)
File "/home/pi/rpiTelecine/rpiTelecine/perforation.py", line 230, in 
findFirstFromCoords
threshVal = int(vROI.max()*self.thresholdVal)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 17, in 
_amax
out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no 
identity
```

This is supposed to be a script which detects the perforation on a strip of film and takes that and determines the crop area when you click on the image area in the preview it generates.

The scripts in question are from github located here:

https://github.com/Alexamder/rpitelecine/blob/master/tc-setupjob.py

Which calls on this one, which seems to be where the problem lies:

https://github.com/Alexamder/rpitelecine/blob/master/rpiTelecine/perforation.py

I came across a suggestion to catch the exception and ignore it from someone encountering a similar error for a different application and thought I might just be able to add an exception:

```
   #take a vertical section of pixels from the ROI and threshold it
try:
    vROI = self.ROIimg[:,xStart-win:xStart+win]
    threshVal = int(vROI.max()*self.thresholdVal)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

By default that code just looks like this:

```
  #take a vertical section of pixels from the ROI and threshold it
        vROI = self.ROIimg[:,xStart-win:xStart+win]
        threshVal = int(vROI.max()*self.thresholdVal)
```

If I add the exception I get this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/rpiTelecine $ sudo python tc-setupjob.py -s8 fats
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tc-setupjob.py", line 44, in <module>
    from tc_common import *
  File "/home/pi/rpiTelecine/tc_common.py", line 39, in <module>
    import rpiTelecine
  File "/home/pi/rpiTelecine/rpiTelecine/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from rpiTelecine.perforation import (
  File "/home/pi/rpiTelecine/rpiTelecine/perforation.py", line 54, in <module>
    class telecinePerforation():
  File "/home/pi/rpiTelecine/rpiTelecine/perforation.py", line 230, in telecinePerforation
    vROI = self.ROIimg[:,xStart-win:xStart+win]
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I'm new to dealing with Python so at the moment I am shooting in the dark and would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please see this post on creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Anyway, there should be a colon (`:`) after the `ValueError`.

Comment: Sorry, I'd truncated the colon, it's actually there. Thank you for your response, and I will work on revising my post.

Comment: You need to wrap the code that throws the error in a [`try/except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) block. You probably didn't add the try statement. Post the code where you added the `except` and someone may be able to help.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reponse, I did not have the try statement in there but now I am getting a different error, I will post it along with the code block.