mplfinance: ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity
I am using mplfinance to chart some data. I have a couple of functions to add scatter plots. These functions work great so long as they do not produce a zero-sized array for the plot. Unfortunately zero data is a realistic situation. One of my functions is as follows:
def get_down_pip_diff(diff, price):
    import numpy as np
    signal = []
    for date2,value in diff.items():
        if value < 0:
            signal.append(price[date2]*1.018)
        else:
            signal.append(np.nan) # This is the line where it goes wrong
    return signal

This is called by this:
down_pip_diff_signal = get_down_pip_diff(df['Pip_Diff'], df['close'])

And this:
mpf.make_addplot(down_pip_diff_signal, type = 'scatter', panel = 0, markersize = 100, marker = 'o', color = 'r'),

So, I know what the problem is, I know where it is, and I know why. I just don't know what I can do about it.
Does anybody have any suggestions, please?
Regards, StuartM

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43299853/valueerror-zero-size-array-to-reduction-operation-maximum-which-has-no-identity

The bottom line is that you should not call mpf.make_addplot() when you have zero size array!
You aren't show the rest of you code, so it is not possible to make further suggestions as to whether or how you may want to indicate for yourself that your signal is empty, or how many addplots you may have.  Assuming you are generating addplots in some kind of a loop, you might try something like this:
addplots = []

# looping here to generate one or more addplots:
    # make_addplot only if signal > 0 and not all `nan`:
    if len(down_pip_diff_signal) > 0 and not np.isnan(down_pip_diff_signal).all():

        addplots.append(mpf.make_addplot(down_pip_diff_signal, type='scatter', 
                                    panel=0, markersize=100, marker='o', color='r'))

# after the loop:

if len(addplots) > 0:
    mpf.plot(data,addplot=addplots,...)
else:
    mpf.plot(data,...)

There are several other ways to do this, some simpler, but as mentioned you are not showing the rest of your code so it is difficult to suggest which way would be best.

Many thanks Daniel, this is exactly what I wanted
